# Create Jar file for different classes in same package

Tags: java, android-studio, cmd, jar

I have four classes defined in same package say `com.test.calc`. 
Four classes are as

**Server.java

Client.java

Util.java

CalcThread.java**

Out of these four classes `Server and Client` have `Main` method defined. 
I want to have jar files of these two classes separately.

I have tried the following commands

```
java -cp server.jar server
```

I have also tried

```
java -cp server.jar com.test.calc.server
```

But this give me error

`Could not find or load main class Server`

How can I achieve this ?

Comment: It might be a typo `java -cp server.jar com.test.calc.server`. The server class is with an uppercase `S`. Have you tried `java -cp server.jar com.test.calc.Server`?

Comment: I have tried both

Comment: Then please post the output of `jar -tf server.jar`. If there is no file `com/test/calc/Server.class` then the package statement in `Server.java` might be wrong.

Comment: I have tried the following commands `D:\Projects\EclipseProjects\Calculator\src\main\java\com\test\calc>jar -tf server.jar`

Comment: It gives me error `Error in opening ZIP file`

Comment: When run command `D:\Projects\EclipseProjects\Calculator\src\main\java\com\tes‌​t\calc>java -cp server.jar com.test.calc.server` it gives me error `Could not load or find class Server,java`

Comment: `Error in opening ZIP file` - seems the file is corrupt. How was it created?